# ASP.NET Core In-Process hosting ASP.NET Core module architecure

Tags: asp.net-core

When we use `dotnet.exe <appname.dll>` to run the dot net core apps or create a service file (systemd) then we mention dotnet.exe to start the app, which calls the hostfxr which finds the CoreCLR and start execution.
With In-Process we don't use dotnet.exe, so how does ASP.NET Core module work internally?

the documentation says CreateDefaultBuilder adds an IServer instance (HttpServer) by calling the `UseIIS` method to boot the CoreCLR and host the app inside of the IIS worker process (w3wp.exe or iisexpress.exe).
**But how is this possible? CreateDefaultBuilder will be called when Main() will be called and CLR will start executing the Main(), then what is meant by boot the CLR? the CLR must be called before the Main() method is called, isn't it**?

Comment: [Does this article useful to you?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/in-process-hosting?view=aspnetcore-6.0)

Comment: sir, the documentation says CreateDefaultBuilder adds an IServer instance (HttpServer) by calling the UseIIS method to boot the CoreCLR and host the app inside of the IIS worker process (w3wp.exe or iisexpress.exe). But how is this possible? CreateDefaultBuilder will be called when Main() will be called then what is meant by boot the CLR? the CLR must be called before the Main() method is called, isn't it